# Updating ID when destroying a has_many / belongs_to element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Have the classes Status and Ticket

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
  attr_accessible :name, :status_id
end
```

In the view, I have a drop down menu where you can select a status for a ticket, where the status IDs are the values of the options. The trouble arrises when I go to delete a status, the status ID for the deleted status is still saved in the tickets. How do I either nullify all the status IDs of the tickets that have that destroyed status, or change the status IDs of those tickets to a active status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:dependent => :destroy` for tickets.

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy  #`:dependent => :nullify` to set all foreign keys to nil
end
```

This will delete the all ticket records for which status is deleted.

Comment: Won't this destroy the associated tickets also? I just want to clear the status ID field, not delete the whole ticket. Don't I want something more like, `:dependent => :nullify`?

Comment: You can write your custom `destroy` method. By overriding default one.

Comment: Ya you can use `:dependent => :nullify`

Comment: I used `:dependent => :nullify`, and added `belongs_to :status, :foreign_key => :status_id` to the ticket model. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This implies that tickets are dependent on status. When a status is destroyed, it will destroy all associated tickets as well.
That's where difference in `#delete` and `#destroy` becomes more prominent.